# Renaming database on Mac in Workbench

Tags: database, mysql-workbench, rename, mysql-shell

I have a task of creating a database in Workbench, MySQL. Unfortunately I used capital letters in the name of the database and later found that there is a bug in Workbench and capital letter names do not allow to dump the database. So it should be renamed into lowercase. ALTER RENAME does not do the trick. Looks like I have to do it in mysql shell. I installed it (MySQL Shell 8.2.1), but I don't think I understand how to connect to my database and dump it.
when in mysql shell, I run
$mysqldump -u <**username - used my username her**e> -p"**password** - used my password to database" -R oldDbName > oldDbName.sql :
$ mysqldump -u fhfhfkozak -p"**password**" -R TTF_Database2 > TTF_Database2.sql
I get "Unexpected identifier 'mysqldump' "
Did anyone have the same problem? Otherwise I have to make this database again, which is not delightful)

I found a solution as follows:
dump the old database via mysql shell
and then create a new database and restore into it the old database tables.

But as I wrote above, I am stuck at the first step:
when in mysql shell, I run
$mysqldump -u <**username - used my username her**e> -p"**password** - used my password to database" -R oldDbName > oldDbName.sql :
$ mysqldump -u fhfhfkozak -p"TheVorsklaofofo" -R TTF_Database2 > TTF_Database2.sql
I get "Unexpected identifier 'mysqldump' "

Comment: You are able to connect to the database, you only have problem exporting it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqldump` looks like a good idea, but you said you have a problem with exporting due to capital letters. Maybe you could dump all databases:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldb.sql
```

Alternatively, you could create a new database and recreate your tables and copy all the data. Then export this new database and maybe drop the old one.